# Why react not rendering updated state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, use-effect, use-state

I have a community feature in my application in which users can post their comments.I want to toggle the state of visibility of a comment when clicked on  a particular icon.
Icon:

```
 <i className="fa-solid fa-message" onClick={(e)=>handleComment(e)}></i>
        {!props.post.isCommentVisible && <> <Container maxW="md" centerContent p={8}>
          {props.post.comment.map((comm) => (
            <Text>{comm}</Text>
          ))}
```

The function to toggle the visiblity of ccomment is:

```
function handleComment(e)
  {
    const id=props.post.id;
    posts.map((post)=>{
      if(post.id==id)
      {
       if(post.isCommentVisible=="false")
       {
         post.isCommentVisible="true";
       }
       else
       {
        post.isCommentVisible="false";
       }
         
         
       db.collection("posts").doc(id).set(post);
      }
    })

  }
```

Interestingly the state of visibility of comment is updated but react is not rerendering the changed state.

Comment: just mutating a prop won't trigger a render, you need to use state (and avoid mutation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether `props.post.isCommentVisible` is `"true"` or `"false"` the expression `!props.post.isCommentVisible` will always be `false` because `"anyString"` is always true.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming somewhere you defined:

```js
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
```

And then updated populated `posts` via some fetch operation, you have to call `setPosts` like:

```js
setPosts(
    posts.map((x) => ({
        ...x,
        isCommentVisible:
            x.id === post.id ? !x.isCommentVisible : x.isCommentVisible,
    }))
);
```

(use any method you want to achieve the result, mind the comment by Rocky Sims)

This will cause the re-render.